# Odoo 9 inherit js file

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

I need to change title in `addons/web/static/src/js/web_client.js`

```
this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});
```

Is it possible in new custom module inherit js file and change "Odoo" to "Odoo 9"

Comment: It most likely is possible. I wish I had more knowledge in the topic of js inheritance, but I dont and so cant give you much advice on that. The easiest method would be to just statically change the code you displayed above. However if you do figure out how to inherit this class and overide the function, please post your code. I for one, would like to know as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it by overriding `start` function:

```
instance.web.WebClient.include({

    start: function() {
        this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo9"});
        return this._super();
    },
});
```

To override a javascript function in odoo, use the following code:

**__openerp__.py**

```
...
'data': [
    'module_view.xml',
],
...
```

**module_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend_custum_id" name="title_365 assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/title_365/static/src/js/script.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**script.js**

```
openerp.title_365 = function(instance){
    var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    instance.web.WebClient.include({

        start: function() {
            this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo9"});
            return this._super();
            },
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WaIR really appreciate that contribution. I will be sure to try and use this. I have made this adjustment in the past just manually changing the entry.

Comment: @phillipstack I am glad to help.

Comment: @WalR Tnx for replay, can you see my module I'm add all from your example but not working. https://postimg.org/image/n3tkqpeh9/  Maybe need change name="name assets" in .xml view?

Comment: @user_odoo Replace `module_name` with you module name (`title_365`) in `script.js`.I edited my code.

Comment: @PhillipStack Odoo framework allows direct modification of an existing class using `include ()` instead of `extend ()` method that will create a new class.