# How override in js file odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I need override in below function ASC to DESC

```
render: function (messages, options) {
        clearTimeout(this.auto_render_timeout);
        var self = this;
        var msgs = _.map(messages, this._preprocess_message.bind(this));
        if (this.options.display_order === ORDER.ASC) {
            msgs.reverse();
        }
```

Source code: https://postimg.org/image/9mxw6ksy7/67729f63/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the function and then call _super(). Include your method in the class which implements this function. A similar question is posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418642/odoo-9-inherit-js-file/40432919#comment68116329_40432919) with a specific implementation which has been tested. My below example has not been tested fully. Remember to install your addon and update it to see your changes.

```
}
'name': "asc_desc",

'summary': """
    Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
    subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

'description': """
    Long description of module's purpose
""",

'author': "My Company",
'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/openerp/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Uncategorized',
'version': '0.1',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views.xml',
    'templates.xml',
    'javascript_import.xml',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo.xml',
],
}
```

javascript_import.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <openerp>
     <data>
         <template id="assets_backend_asc_desc" name="assets_backend_asc_desc" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
             <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="/asc_desc/static/src/js/asc.js"></script>
             </xpath>
         </template>
     </data>
 </openerp>
```

asc.js

```
odoo.define('asc_desc.ChatThread', function(require){
"use strict"
var core = require('web.core');
var QWeb = core.qweb;
var thread = require('mail.ChatThread');

var ORDER = {
    DESC: -1,
    ASC: 1,
}

thread.include({
    render: function (messages, options) {
        console.log("TEST");
        var msgs = _.map(messages, this._preprocess_message.bind(this));
        if (this.options.display_order === ORDER.DESC) {
            msgs.reverse();
        }
        options = _.extend({}, this.options, options);

        // Hide avatar and info of a message if that message and the previous
        // one are both comments wrote by the same author at the same minute
        var prev_msg;
        _.each(msgs, function (msg) {
            if (!prev_msg || (Math.abs(msg.date.diff(prev_msg.date)) > 60000) || prev_msg.message_type !== 'comment' || msg.message_type !== 'comment' || (prev_msg.author_id[0] !== msg.author_id[0])) {
                msg.display_author = true;
            } else {
                msg.display_author = !options.squash_close_messages;
            }
            prev_msg = msg;
        });

        this.$el.html(QWeb.render('mail.ChatThread', {
            messages: msgs,
            options: options,
            ORDER: ORDER,
        }));
    },

});

});
```

Ensure you include the file declaring your js in your `__openerp__.py` file.

Comment: @Philip Stack  Can you hlep me, what is JSClass in my example --> https://postimg.org/image/qbt4ysz77/

Comment: Not sure, I think o_mail_thread however. It looks like you just need to determine where the options are defined. This is sometimes in the xml. Or in this case, it may also be qweb which basically amounts to the same thing. You may be able to override the xml or qweb and pass the option 'display_order":ORDER.DESC. But I am not sure. You need to go backward and determine where the options are defined.

Comment: @Philip Stack In new custom module I want override ASC to DESC. Here is my code https://postimg.org/image/mi9u7c6yn/  Maybe is problem in inherit ID? How find correct inherit ID?

Comment: If you place some logging in the render function. It should run whenever the mail widget display. That will tell you if your code is even running.

Comment: If you get no logging and no error then your code is not being used at all. It appears that if you look at the init function that the default is DESC. Maybe you could overide the init function and switch the default.

Comment: After change in original mail source in render Asc to Desc all work fine...

Comment: What about the logging. Is your js code being executed?

Comment: When you click on the chat button you should see the logging appear in your browser console indicating that the code is executing.

Comment: @Philip Stack My discuss form not loading I think taht is here problem --> https://postimg.org/image/5ck91coqr/

Comment: In console I don't see "EXECUTING RENDER"!

Comment: I am updating the code. My guess is that the declaration of you js is incorrect. When I click on the discuss widget I see "EXECUTING RENDER" in the console. It really should be running.

Comment: @Philip Stack  After copy your example in my module and install on discuss page message don't apear, after delete render message appear https://postimg.org/image/j4m781ihz/

Comment: I was using the render function I had seen in one of your screen shots. I replaced it with what I found in the mail addon. Mine looks a little different. Anyways, my messages are showing up.

Comment: Would you please provide the path to the js you are trying to overide? I am wondering if I am looking at the wrong module. Because the js code in my addon appears different than what I saw in yours.

Comment: Have you tried the new code I pasted? This is working on my system.

Comment: I wont be offended if you up vote my post or mark it as correct. Honestly.  Glad you have it working. I think we both learned a little more about javascript inheritance in Odoo.