# Change Odoo 11 Title Bar

Tags: javascript, odoo-11

I want to change the page title in the browser for odoo
 i add a .JS in new module but this for Odoo 9

```
openerp.title_365 = function(instance){
    var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    instance.web.WebClient.include({

        start: function() {
            this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "My_title"});
            return this._super();
            },
        });
}
```

I found that in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418642/odoo-9-inherit-js-file#_=_),
how to change to odoo 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below js code.

**Note:** Do not forget to change the module name.

```js
odoo.define('<your module name>.AbstractWebClient', function (require) {
"use strict";

var ActionManager = require('web.ActionManager');
var concurrency = require('web.concurrency');
var core = require('web.core');
var config = require('web.config');
var crash_manager = require('web.crash_manager');
var data_manager = require('web.data_manager');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
var Loading = require('web.Loading');
var mixins = require('web.mixins');
var NotificationManager = require('web.notification').NotificationManager;
var RainbowMan = require('web.rainbow_man');
var session = require('web.session');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');

var AbstractWebClient = require('web.AbstractWebClient');

AbstractWebClient.include({
 init: function (parent) {
        this.client_options = {};
        mixins.ServiceProvider.init.call(this);
        this._super(parent);
        this.origin = undefined;
        this._current_state = null;
        this.menu_dm = new concurrency.DropMisordered();
        this.action_mutex = new concurrency.Mutex();
        this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "My Title"});
    },
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change title on login page follow these setps

1. Activate **developer mode**
2. Go to **User Interface** and click **views**
3. Search **layout** and select `web.layout` template
4. Change title from here
5. Edit title as per you need